# Page Size issues

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

Hope you're doing great!

I wanted to check if you could take a look at some issue I have with a challenge

when opening this website via deploy on github or netilify I get the page with higher zoom like if it was over 100%

when I open it on liveserver from vscode or directly via HTML file it will open with its content size correctly, I added the font-size base to tailwind config 16px or 100% and it made it work when opening via HTML file, but still not working on when I deploy the doc

Doc

https://github.com/Ramses1406/Chat-app-Ram.git

live site
https://incandescent-jelly-e743c6.netlify.app/

https://ramses1406.github.io/Chat-app-Ram/

Code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Chat-App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/output.css" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/images/favicon-32x32.png" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css"
      integrity="sha512-DTOQO9RWCH3ppGqcWaEA1BIZOC6xxalwEsw9c2QQeAIftl+Vegovlnee1c9QX4TctnWMn13TZye+giMm8e2LwA=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
    />
  </head>
  <body
    class="lg:items-center lg:flex lg:flex-row lg:bg-Secondary-LightGrayishViolet lg:gap-[8rem]"
  >
    <!--FORMA_BG-->

    <div class="">
      <div
        class="w-[13rem] rounded-br-full lg:rounded-b-full lg:h-[55rem] lg:w-[35rem] h-[40rem] bg-gradient-to-t from-[#983BFE] to-[#D643FE] absolute"
      ></div>

      <main class="px-10 py-20 lg:ml-[31rem] bg-Secondary-LightGrayishViolet">
        <!-- main cel -->
        <div class="flex items-center justify-center">
          <!-- CEL MAIN BG -->
          <div class="z-10 p-3 py-5 bg-white rounded-3xl">
            <!-- header PURPLE -->
            <div
              class="flex items-center justify-between bg-gradient-to-r rounded-b-md rounded-t-2xl from-[#983BFE] to-[#D643FE] px-6 py-8 relative"
            >
              <div
                class="absolute w-[10rem] h-[2rem] bg-white left-[7.3rem] bottom-[5rem] rounded-b-3xl"
              ></div>

              <div class="flex items-center justify-start gap-2">
                <i class="text-white fa-solid fa-angle-left"></i>

                <div>
                  <img
                    src="./images/avatar.jpg"
                    class="h-10 rounded-full border-[2px] white border-"
                    alt=""
                  />
                </div>
                <div>
                  <h1 class="text-lg text-white">Samuel Green</h1>
                  <p class="text-xs text-white/40">Available to Walk</p>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div>
                <i class="text-white fa-solid fa-ellipsis-vertical"></i>
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- BG- INSIDE CEL -->
            <div
              class="px-4 pt-5 pb-4 rounded-b-2xl bg-Secondary-LightGrayishViolet"
            >
              <!-- CHAT -->
              <section>
                <p
                  class="px-3 py-2 mb-2 rounded-lg text-[#9e38a9] text-sm bg-primary-GrayishBlue/40 w-fit"
                >
                  That sounds great. <br />
                  I’d be happy with that.
                </p>

                <p
                  class="px-3 py-2 mb-2 text-sm rounded-lg text-[#9e38a9] bg-primary-GrayishBlue/40 w-fit"
                >
                  Could you send over some <br />
                  pictures of your dog, please?
                </p>

                <!-- RESPUESTAS -->
                <div class="flex justify-end gap-3 item-self">
                  <img
                    src="/images/dog-image-1.jpg"
                    class="h-12 rounded-lg"
                    alt=""
                  />
                  <img
                    src="/images/dog-image-2.jpg"
                    class="h-12 rounded-lg"
                    alt=""
                  />
                  <img
                    src="/images/dog-image-3.jpg"
                    class="h-12 rounded-lg"
                    alt=""
                  />
                </div>

                <div class="flex flex-col items-end">
                  <p class="px-3 py-2 mb-2 text-sm bg-white rounded-lg w-fit">
                    Here are a few pictures. She’s a happy girl!
                  </p>
                  <p class="px-3 py-2 mb-2 text-sm bg-white rounded-lg w-fit">
                    Can you make it?
                  </p>
                </div>

                <p
                  class="px-3 py-2 mb-2 text-sm rounded-lg text-[#9e38a9] bg-primary-GrayishBlue/40 w-fit"
                >
                  She looks so happy! The time <br />
                  we discussed works. How <br />
                  long shall I take her out for?
                </p>
              </section>

              <div
                class="flex justify-between gap-2 py-5 rounded-lg rounded-bl-none px-14 bg-gradient-to-l from-[#983BFE] to-[#D643FE] max-w-[17rem] mb-2"
              >
                <p class="text-sm text-white/60">30 minute walk</p>
                <span class="text-lg font-bold text-white"> $29 </span>
              </div>

              <div
                class="flex justify-between gap-2 py-5 rounded-lg rounded-bl-none px-14 bg-gradient-to-l from-[#983BFE] to-[#D643FE] max-w-[17rem]"
              >
                <p class="text-sm text-white/60">1 hour walk</p>
                <span class="text-lg font-bold text-white"> $49 </span>
              </div>

              <!-- TYPING BAR -->

              <div
                class="relative flex items-center justify-between px-20 py-3 mx-auto mt-2 bg-white rounded-3xl"
              >
                <input type="text" placeholder="Type a message..." />

                <i
                  class="absolute fa-solid fa-circle-chevron-right right-[0.6rem] opacity-80 text-4xl"
                ></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>

    <div
      class="px-10 pt-12 pb-20 lg:min-w-[50rem] bg-Secondary-LightGrayishViolet"
    >
      <h1 class="text-6xl font-bold text-center lg:text-start">
        Simple booking
      </h1>

      <p
        class="pt-4 text-lg font-medium leading-[1.9rem] lg:text-start text-center text-gray-400 lg:hidden"
      >
        Stay in touch with our dog walkers <br />
        through the chat interface. This makes it <br />
        easy to discuss arrangements and make <br />
        bookings. Once the walk has been <br />
        completed you can rate your walker and <br />
        book again all through the chat.
      </p>

      <pre class="text-lg text-gray-400 text-start max-lg:hidden">

Stay in touch with our dog walkers  through the chat
interface. This makes it   easy to discuss arrangements and 
make bookings.Once the walk has been completed you can
rate your walker and  book again all through the chat.
        </pre
      >
    </div>

    <!-- BG-FORM #2 -->
    <div
      class="w-[13rem] max-lg:hidden opacity-5 lg:rounded-t-full lg:h-[55rem] lg:w-[35rem] h-[40rem] bg-gradient-to-t from-[#983BFE] to-[#D643FE] absolute transform translate-x-[90rem] translate-y-[8rem]"
    ></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet** using the `<>` icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, I just added the code